# How to write a line to end of a file every 'x' seconds

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a line to a file every 5 seconds continuously. So let us say I have a `String = Hello world` and I run my code for 15 seconds my output should be a file containing the data

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello world
```

What I have so far is that my file only every contains one line of `Hello World` rather than the required 3.

My code so far looks like this:

```
public class MyFileWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1000);
        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                FileWriter fw = null;
                try {
                    fw = new FileWriter("Test5.txt");
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    fw.write("Hello World");

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

What is confusing me is if I change the method `run` to just print out `Hello World` rather than write it to a file it will print it out every 5 seconds so the error must lie in how I'm writing it. I think for some reason it just writes `Hello World` on the first line over and over again.

Comment: You want [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)) contructor of class `java.io.FileWriter`.

Comment: Each time you open the file, you are overwriting the previous content. Open the file in _append_ mode. `new FileWriter("Test5.txt", true)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At every iteration, you re-open your file using a `FileWriter`. By default, it starts writing at the beginning of the file, thus overwriting its contents with always the same "Hello World" string.

If you want to add that sentence to the end, then you want to set the "append" option when instanciating your `FileWriter`. Also append a line separator each time:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1000);
  ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {

          FileWriter fw = null;
          try {
              fw = new FileWriter("Test5.txt", true);
          } catch (IOException e1) {

              e1.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
              fw.write("Hello World");
              fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
          } catch (IOException e) {

              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
              fw.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {

              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }

  }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Such a small snippet, so many issues with it.

1. You're opening the file in overwrite mode, so every 5 seconds, you're overwriting the previous one-line of `Hello`, with a new line of `Hello`. You'd want to open it in append mode.
2. Do not, ever, write to a file using 'default charset encoding'. That is a funny way of saying 'something you never want'. The easy fix to all of this is to not use this outdated API. Use `java.nio.file` instead.
3. You aren't properly guarding your resource. Use try-with-resources (at this point, that's a 10 year old java feature. You're going by some **old** tutorials, find some better ones :P)
4. Your exception handling is in a word deplorable. If something is wrong with this file, you'll get 3 prints per error (each of the 3 exceptions will trigger). As a genreal rule, `e.printStackTrace();` is something you should never be writing. When an error occurs, you [A] toss away a lot of useful information, [B] dump it to syserr which is rarely a proper place for it, and worst of all [C] your code just keeps going even though *clearly* something happened you didn't expect, and consequently, you cannot possibly claim your code knows what to do now. And yet you keep going. Generally, if you don't know what to do with an error, best option is to just throw it onwards (add `throws X` to your method declaration). If you can't do that, wrap the exception (`throw new RuntimeException(e);` - or for IOExceptions specifically, `throw new UncheckedIOException(e);`). Update your IDE. Also, don't write 3 catch blocks, combine them.

Let's fix all of that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1000);
  Path path = Paths.get("Test5.txt");

  ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
      // The new API defaults to UTF_8 instead of 'system encoding'.
      Files.write(path, List.of("Hello World"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    } // EDIT: I forgot this brace before.
  }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

That looks a lot simpler, doesn't it?

NB: Try-with-resources is not needed now, as we can just call `write` which opens, writes, and closes all in one go, and thus needs no try-with.

Comment: In all honesty this is very useful! I'll keep these in mind. The reason for this code is to just check that my method of reading/writing from files will not lock a file it doesn't need to be fancy or proper by any means. I'd just clicked all of eclipses suggested fixes to my code. I'm going to write some more code which will read from this file whilst this code in the post writes to it. I'm going to be working with log files so I want to be able to read from a log file whilst something else is writing to it so I was just using this as a test. But you are right that does look a lot simpler!

Comment: Added on, as I ran out of characters. What version of Java are you using I'm getting an error with that code. It says `scheduleAtFixedRate` is missing arguments. I add arguments and I get an error telling me to remove the arguments?

Comment: @ConnorGill I accidentally a brace. I'll fix the code snippet.